# Drupal 7. Taxonomy. Term name override

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-taxonomy

I have vocabulary Angle, with terms: 10, 15, 20 etc.
I want to have taxonomy page h1 title "Angle $term_name mm" - Angle 10mm, Angle 15mm..
Please push me on the right way or just help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using modules like `Panels` or `Views` to show taxonomy terms, you may implement `hook_preprocess_taxonomy_term()` in your theme:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables) {
  $term = $variables['term'];
  // Alter only terms of Angle vocabulary.
  if ($term->vocabulary_machine_name == 'angle') {
    // Alter only taxonomy term pages, not listings.
    if ($variables['page']) {
      $name = t('Angle @name mm', array('@name' => $term->name));
      drupal_set_title($name);
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. Why not using correct term names from the start? If you need raw angle values (10, 15 etc.) you may add corresponding numeric field to your vocabulary.